# How can I append a textarea value to run through an array

Tags: jquery, forms, append

I have an array created by taking the values of all the links in a div, when I add the values to a textarea to send them to my server, it's only pulling the last one, using console I noticed that the array is holding all the values, as is the alert when I set it, so how can I concatenate all the values into one long string with commas or something? Here's my code

```
 $(".populate").click(function(){
   var array = $.makeArray( $('li.item-link a'));
   jQuery.each(array, function(index, value) {
     console.log("index", index, "value", value);
     alert(value);
     $("#CAT_Custom_196863").val(value);
   });
 });
```

Anyone any ideas?

All the Best
Tara

Comment: Loads of excellent suggestions, I'm dying to try them later! I'll let you know :) thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$("#CAT_Custom_196863").val(value);` line is setting the **entire** value to the latest `value`.

Instead use something like:

```
$("#CAT_Custom_196863").val($("#CAT_Custom_196863").val() + ', ' + value);
```

Comment: It's an unnecessary overhead to get `#CAT_Custom_196863` and create a jQuery object on each iteration. If there are a lot of links, this can be really slow

Comment: Yes I agree that it is however, it clearly shows to the op what it is doing and I did only say to use something *like* that. Without knowing the context of the OPs useage, it's impossible to know whether there'll actually be any perceivable impact on speed. Your answer is more correct though, so +1 to you!

Answer (score 1):

The val method replaces the current value. Try this instead:

```
$(".populate").click(function(){
   var array = $.makeArray( $('li.item-link a'));
   var newVal = '';
   jQuery.each(array, function(index, value) {
     console.log("index", index, "value", value);
     alert(value);
     newVal += value + ','; // comma?
   });

   // In order to skip the last comma, uncomment this line:
   // if(newVal.length > 0) newVal = newVal.substr(0, newVal.length - 1);

   $("#CAT_Custom_196863").val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: OP wants comma separated or something so adjust `newVal += value;` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I missed that he wrote "with commas" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join method of Javascript arrays:

```
$("#CAT_Custom_196863").val($.MakeArray($('li.item-link a')).join(", "));
```

BTW Blair McMillan is correct, you're setting the entire value, not adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.map(arr, function(value, index) {
    return arr.join(",");
});
```

rest is *logic*